# Ubuntu 16.04 and AMDGPU-PRO Driver

Tags: drivers, graphics, amd-graphics, opengl

I'm getting the following output from glxinfo:

`$ glxinfo | grep OpenGL
Xlib:  extension "AMDGPU" missing on display ":0".
OpenGL vendor string: Advanced Micro Devices, Inc.
OpenGL renderer string: AMD Radeon (TM) R9 Fury Series
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.5.13468 Core Profile Context 16.60.3
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
Xlib:  extension "AMDGPU" missing on display ":0".
OpenGL version string: 4.5.13468 Compatibility Profile Context 16.60.3
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL context flags: (none)
OpenGL profile mask: compatibility profile
OpenGL extensions:
Xlib:  extension "AMDGPU" missing on display ":0".
OpenGL ES profile version string: 4.5.13468 Compatibility Profile Context 16.60.3
OpenGL ES profile shading language version string: 4.50
OpenGL ES profile extensions:`

I'm concerned about the Xlib lines. Or rather, are those lines an actual problem? Recently tried to play a game and had no audio as well as other bugs and I'm trying to rule out/identify my driver as a related problem.

Here is a link to the driver release notes: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

I couldn't find anything helpful with google, however I figure I'm not using the right search strings. I just pasted the Xlib line hoping that error happened to someone before, and it didn't. At least not for this driver.

The game I'm trying to play is Dead Island Definitive Edition. I did post on the steam forum, but seeing as there's no related info currently on that board, I doubt I'll get an intellegent response there.

Any help is much appreciated.

Comment: Did you have any success resolving this as I'm encountering the same problem with R9 Nano?

Comment: Nothing so far. Turns out that Dead Island Definitive Edition is jank even on windows so I returned it but I have tried a few other games in linux since and they seemed to run but didn't perform well, yet perfect in windows. Dunno if that's just how it is or if there's a problem with my driver setup.

Comment: I've decided and emailed AMD support (since I'm at university and we have some relation with them), although I doubt will get any answer for resolving this...

Comment: 17.10 just came out: http://support.amd.com/en-us/kb-articles/Pages/AMDGPU-PRO-Driver-for-Linux-Release-Notes.aspx

same issue

Comment: It seems the problem is gone in 17.30